# Remove Dictionaries from List of Dictionaries with similar unsorted values

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, dictionary

I have a list of dictionarys listed below:

```
[{'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'banana'},
 {'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'apple', 'slice3': 'grape'}, 
 {'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'apple'}, #duplicate to be removed
 {'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'apple', 'slice3': 'apple'},
 {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'apple'}, #duplicate to be removed 
 {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'banana', 'slice3': 'grape'},
 {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'banana', 'slice3': 'banana'},
 {'slice1': 'grape', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'apple'},
 {'slice1': 'grape', 'slice2': 'apple', 'slice3': 'grape'}, #duplicate to be removed
 {'slice1': 'grape','slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'grape'}]
```

In my code, I later run these dictionaries through a loop, however, I don't need to run each of the dictionaries because some of them are duplicates because the order of the "slice" keys doesn't matter. For instance a dictionary that is:

```
{'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'banana'}
```

Is the same as

```
{'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'banana', 'slice3': 'grape'}
```

What I would like to do is create a list of dictionaries removing these 'duplicate' dictionaries. From the original list of dictionaries, if I were to remove the "duplicates" it would leave me with a list like the below:

```
[{'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'banana'},
 {'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'apple', 'slice3': 'grape'},
 {'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'apple', 'slice3': 'apple'},
 {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'banana', 'slice3': 'grape'},
 {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'banana', 'slice3': 'banana'},
 {'slice1': 'grape', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'apple'},
 {'slice1': 'grape','slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'grape'}]
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use equality checks such as `==`, `!=` with dictionaries, e.g. `filtered_list = [d for d in dictionaries if d != test_dictionary]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might do it by building a dict with `tuple(sorted(values))` as the key; then take the `values` of that dict:

```
>>> data = [{'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'banana'},
...  {'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'apple', 'slice3': 'grape'},
...  {'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'apple'}, #duplicate to be removed
...  {'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'apple', 'slice3': 'apple'},
...  {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'apple'}, #duplicate to be removed
...  {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'banana', 'slice3': 'grape'},
...  {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'banana', 'slice3': 'banana'},
...  {'slice1': 'grape', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'apple'},
...  {'slice1': 'grape', 'slice2': 'apple', 'slice3': 'grape'}, #duplicate to be removed
...  {'slice1': 'grape','slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'grape'}]
>>> {tuple(sorted(d.values())): d for d in data}.values()
dict_values([
    {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'apple'}, 
    {'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'apple'}, 
    {'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'apple', 'slice3': 'apple'}, 
    {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'banana', 'slice3': 'grape'},
    {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'banana', 'slice3': 'banana'},
    {'slice1': 'grape', 'slice2': 'apple', 'slice3': 'grape'},
    {'slice1': 'grape', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'grape'}
])
```

Comment: Cool, it's a nice one

Answer (score 1):

Use a set to keep track of all values you have seen, and add dict to the result list if it's not seen yet:

```
seen = set()
result = []

for d in lst:
    vals = tuple(sorted(d.values())) # sort the values so order doesn't matter
    if vals not in seen:
        seen.add(vals)
        result.append(d)

result
[{'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'banana'}, 
 {'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'apple', 'slice3': 'grape'}, 
 {'slice1': 'apple', 'slice2': 'apple', 'slice3': 'apple'}, 
 {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'banana', 'slice3': 'grape'}, 
 {'slice1': 'banana', 'slice2': 'banana', 'slice3': 'banana'}, 
 {'slice1': 'grape', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'apple'}, 
 {'slice1': 'grape', 'slice2': 'grape', 'slice3': 'grape'}]
```